# Highlighting on has_child query

Tags: elasticsearch

In some of our types, we have a parent child setup and we want to search on parent fields and also on the child fields (and return parent) and we do query like below. When there is a has_child match is there any way to get highlighting information from the child match even though the parent is being returned. As an example, if we have mapping like the following:

```
PUT nested2
{
  "mappings":{
    "discussion":{
        "properties" : {
            "title":{
                "type":"string"
            }
        }
    },
    "discussionPost":{
        "_parent":{
            "type" : "discussion"
        },
        "properties" : {
            "post" : {
                "type" : "string"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And we issue a query like below, highlight information is returned if there is a match on parent field but not if the parent is being returned due to a has_child match:

```
POST nested2/discussion/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "prefix": {
                    "_all" : "cat"
                }    
            },
            {   
                "has_child" : {
                    "type" : "discussionPost",
                    "score_mode" : "sum",
                    "query" : {
                        "prefix": {
                            "_all" : "cat"
                        }  
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight":{
    "fields":{
      "*":{}
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get highlight information on what matched in the child when has_child query is being issued on the parent?

Regards
LT

Comment: You can do it with two queries easily enough, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking. I don't think there is currently a way to do it with one query.

Comment: It's coming, though: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-inner-hits.html

Comment: Thanks Sloan. I guess for now I will do two separate queries - either run my original query and then run a second query on the child to get highlight information filtered to only those parents that I'm missing highlight information, or else just run two separate queries, one for the parent and one for the child and combine the results programatically.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this using `inner_hits` inside the `has_child` query clause:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {   
                "has_child" : {
                    "inner_hits": {
                        "_source": false,
                        "highlight":{
                            "order": "score",
                            "fields": {"*":{}}
                        }
                    },
                    "type" : "discussionPost",
                    "score_mode" : "sum",
                    "query" : {
                        "prefix": {
                            "_all" : "cat"
                        }  
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```